# Validating through foreach in PHP

Tags: php

Hi can some one help me out with the following. This prints every time `Empty!` or `Full!`  whenever there is a blank or a non blank text box is detected.

What I need is the following;

1. Out of the series of text boxes (in the array) even only one text is detected blank just echo `Empty!` **ONLY ONCE** not every time there a blank textbox.
2. If **ONLY** all the text boxes are non-blank, then echo `Full!` only
   **ONCE!**

How do you suggest that I change the following? Thank you.

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    if(is_array($_POST['name']))
    {
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $Value)
        {if($Value == '')
            {
            echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Response</td></tr></table>";
            echo "Empty!";
            } 
            else 
            {
            echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Response</td></tr></table>";
            echo "Full";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
echo "<td><input style='width:60px' type='text' name='name[]' id='vtext' class='sc_two'     size='80' maxlength='5'></td>
```

then in a validation code I have the following;

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    if($_POST['name']=='')
    {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Responses</td></tr></table>";
    echo "Empty";} 
    else 
    {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Responses</td></tr></table>";
    echo "Saved!";}
}
```

Comment: Is this inside a function? If not, what is `return;` doing in your Empty branch?

Comment: `<table border='1'><tr><td>Response</td></tr></table>`... seriously?

Comment: can you show your actual form code ?

Comment: @andrewsi sorry I removed it. This originally sits inside an echo. I missed removing it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Pls see the Edit. Hope you get in to my mind

Comment: look at the answers below. I think they should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['Save'])) {
    if(is_array($_POST['name'])) {

        $result = 'Full!'; // Result defaults to 'Full!'

        // But if we find an empty value we change it to 'Empty!'
        foreach($_POST['name'] as $value){
            if($value === ''){
                $result = 'Empty!';
                break;
            }
        }

        // Output the response
?>
        <table border="1"><tr><td>Response</td></tr></table>
        <?=$result?>
<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    if(is_array($_POST['name']))
    {
     $full = 0;
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $Value){
        if($Value == '')
            {
            $full = ++;
            } 
        }
    }
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Response</td></tr></table>";
    echo $full == 0 ? "Full" : "Empty" //Shorthand if notation
}
```

You have to run your checks then output the response outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, use `array_search` to tell if there's an empty element in the array.

```
if (array_search('', $_POST['name'])) {
  $result = 'Empty!';
} else {
  $result = 'Full!';
}
echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>Response</td></tr></table>';
echo $result;
```